# Centralizar div no mobile

Tags: html, css

Como centralizar as box em dispositivos mobile? Acontece que nos dispositivos móveis as box ficam grudados no lado direito da tela

```css
.servico{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.servico .servicebox{
    position: relative;
    width: 290px;
    height: 290px;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(10, 24, 46);
    border-radius: 11px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.servico .servicebox .icon{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:  hsl(218, 58%, 16%);
    transition: 00.5s;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 2;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.servico .servicebox .icon i{
    font-size: 3em;
    color: rgb(99, 251, 215);
    transition: 0s;
}
.servico .servicebox:hover > .icon{
    top: 30px;
    left: calc(50% - 40px);
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.servico .servicebox .content{
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.servico .servicebox:hover .content{
    transform: scale(1);
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.servico .servicebox h3{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="servico">  
  <div class="servicebox">
    <div class="icon">
      <p>Icone</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Desenvolvimento de sites</h3>
      <p>test </p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="servicebox">
    <div class="icon">
      <p>Icone</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Search Engine</h3>
      <p>Suporte, configuração e relatório de sites.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="servicebox">
    <div class="icon">
      <p>Icone</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bota `padding: 20px 0;` na class `.servico` que resolve o problema.

Answer (score -2):

Em teste de responsividade que realizei as boxes não ficam grudadas na direita, mas ficam sim descentralizadas para a direita.
Isto está sendo causado pelo `padding` na div `servico`.
Deixe-o da forma abaixo e ele centralizará.

```
.servico{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Valeu! Você ajudou bastante.